# How come the order of parameters doesn't matter in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

Why it seems that in `check()` function it doesn't matter if I pass the parameters as `check(x,y)` or `check(y,x)`?

I tried shifting `x` and `y` to see if it would give me a different output

```
import random

def guess(a, b):
    x = random.randint(a, b)
    return x

def check(a, b):
    if y**2 == x:
        print(x)
        print(y)
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
x = 100
left, right = 0, x

y = guess(left, right)

while not check(x, y): 
    y = guess(left, right)
    
print("answer", y)
```

Comment: Because `check` doesn't use `a` or `b` at all.

Comment: This is called "shadowing" when you use the same variable names in an inner scope that already exist in an outer scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making a salad between `(a,b)` and `(x,y)`.

Your function `check` uses the *"global"* (from the outer scope) `x` and `y` and not the `(x,y)` you pass it in the call `check(x,y)`.

Maybe you meant to use `a` and `b` instead of `x` and `y` inside the definition of `check`.

---

You function expects to get 2 arguments as your signature suggests (`def check(a, b):`) but then nowhere inside it you actually use those arguments. Instead you use `x` and `y`. This does not raise an error because Python looks in the outer scopes for those variables and finds them. If you want the order to matter you should change to:

```py
def check(a, b):
    if b**2 == a:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. That's exactly what I wanted to understand.